# Car feels imbalanced but difficult to find problem

Tags: suspension, hyundai, wheel-balance, tuscani

I have a Hyundai Tuscani Coupe 2006.  One day I was driving fast and there was a ditch in one side of the road.  Thinking I'm a rally racer I just went into the ditch and noticed the rear of the car go bang into it.  Afterwards the car started to steer to the left quite a bit and I noticed it became an intermittent problem. Sometimes the steering just feels very imbalanced.

I took it to tracking they said nothing wrong it and I took it to a garage and they said nothing wrong with the suspension.  I still  notice it feels imbalanced and heavy at times with high fuel consumption but at other times it seems ok.  After going over bumps I especially notice it can steer to the left.

If the tracking ans suspension is ok what else could be the cause of this?

Comment: Would by tracking you mean alignment? If you got an alignment, did you get a printout of all the angles? If so, could you post them? If you didn't get an alignment then you may need one to at least check if anything is out of whack. Be sure they do a thrust angle alignment and not a centerline one. Of course, make sure to get a printout after they are done.

Answer (score 1):

If you still believe something is not right. You need to have another 4 wheel alignment check done on your vehicle, and specify that you require camber & caster angles checking too. Explain to the technician what  has happened to the car and what you are experiencing.. Many tyre and general garages only do a basic check with regards to tracking. Due to the circumstances your vehicle requires a full suspension and 4 wheel alignment check.

At the same time every suspension link, arm and bushing should be closely investigated, as these items can be moved or damaged at the point of an impact and damage is not always initially obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, get an alignment done if you haven't already. You can also check if there is damage to the tyres or wheels. Maybe the drop into the ditch warped one of your wheels or damaged the tyre which can cause imbalanced steering.